# Code snipped runs in JSFiddle but not in my IDE (add 30 minutes to time)?

Tags: javascript

The Code about adding 30 minutes to entered time in Input field, works in jsfiddle but not in my IDE.
I created a new test.php where the html form goes and a new script.js where the js goes.

In my test.php file:

```
<html>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="time" name="zeitstart" class="zeitangaben" id="start"><br>

    <input type="time" name="zeitende" id="ende" class="ende">

    <input type="submit" value="senden">
</form>

</html>
```

In my script.js file:

```
// Element per ID abrufen
const start = document.getElementById('start');
const end = document.getElementById('ende');
// EventListener hinzufügen
start.addEventListener('change', () => {
    // Stunden &  Minuten als INT
    let hours = parseInt(start.value.split(':')[0]);
    let minutes = parseInt(start.value.split(':')[1]);
    // 30 Min hinzufügen
    minutes += 30;
    // Wenn eine volle Stunde überschritten ist, soll die nächste anfangen
    // Wenn 24 Std um sind, von vorne anfangen (nächster Tag)
    if (minutes >= 60) {
        hours = (hours + 1) % 24;
        minutes -= 60;
    }
    // Zeichenfolge mit einer festen länge von 2 formatieren
    hours = (hours < 10 ? `0${hours}` : `${hours}`);
    minutes = (minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : `${minutes}`);
    // const end den neuen Wert zuweisen
    end.value = `${hours}:${minutes}`;
});
```

Both files are in the same direction. 
Any idea?

Comment: Hint: Don't write comments such as `// EventListener hinzufügen`. The function `addEventListener` expresses exactly the same as your comment does. This way you just overload your code with redundant comments. ;)

Comment: Try to include the script.js after body tag. I have tried your code in localsystem and it work if i add script code in same file and at the end

Comment: @GentleSama Yes u are right, I will change it. :)

Comment: It's usually a really bad idea to use non-English terms and variable names.

Comment: You picked an answer that is **invalid HTML**. Browsers would even be free not to execute the script at all written like that. The only allowed child elements of the `html` element are `head` and `body`.

Comment: Downvoted for picking an answer that suggests invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three different ways to include the script code:
 1. script tag with src path(external javascript)
 2. script code before 
 3. wrap the code in document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { /* your code */ });

Try to include `script.js` after body tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
   <form>
    <input type="time" name="zeitstart" class="zeitangaben" id="start"><br>

    <input type="time" name="zeitende" id="ende" class="ende">

    <input type="submit" value="senden">
</form>

</body>
    <script>
        const start = document.getElementById('start');
        const end = document.getElementById('ende');
        // EventListener hinzufügen
        start.addEventListener('change', () => {
            // Stunden &  Minuten als INT
            let hours = parseInt(start.value.split(':')[0]);
            let minutes = parseInt(start.value.split(':')[1]);
            // 30 Min hinzufügen
            minutes += 30;
            // Wenn eine volle Stunde überschritten ist, soll die nächste anfangen
            // Wenn 24 Std um sind, von vorne anfangen (nächster Tag)
            if (minutes >= 60) {
                hours = (hours + 1) % 24;
                minutes -= 60;
            }
            // Zeichenfolge mit einer festen länge von 2 formatieren
            hours = (hours < 10 ? `0${hours}` : `${hours}`);
            minutes = (minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : `${minutes}`);
            // const end den neuen Wert zuweisen
            end.value = `${hours}:${minutes}`;
        });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: That is invalid HTML. If the intention is to execute code only after the DOM is parsed, you have three options: Either include the code right **before** `</body>`, *or* include it with `<script src="./path/to/script.js" defer></script>`, *or* wrap the code in `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { /* your code */ });`.

Comment: You should correct your answer. Unfortunately, as it stands, OP has picked your (invalid) answer. This is misleading for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is executed before the DOM is loaded. The simplest solution is to move the script tag to the end of the HTML file.

Or you can add an event listener for when the window is loaded.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

```
window.addEventListener('load', function handler() {
    // your code
});
```

The reason why this is working on jsFiddle is that the binding between the javascript file and the HTML file is done by them (in the correct order).

Comment: seems realistic :) Thank you too!

Comment: You're welcome. :)

As a piece of advice, I think it's better to use non-anonymous functions for handlers because it will give a clear understanding of where things went off if you will have an error.

Comment: `load` waits for all static resources to be fully loaded (images, fonts, svg, etc). If you don't need that and only want to make sure the DOM is parsed and the elements are queryable, use `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Comment: @robert The main reason not to use anonymous functions for event handling: You cannot remove those listeners later.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is that your script is being executed before the browser has parsed the DOM (the HTML), making the elements unavailable for querying at the time of script execution.

To make sure code is only executed after the DOM is parsed, you have three options:

1. Include the code right **before** `</body>`,
2. include it wherever you want (usually in the `head`) with `defer` attribute

   ```
   <script src="./path/to/script.js" defer></script>
   ```
3. wrap the code in

   ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { /* your code */ });
   ```

If you want to delay code execution until all the static resources like images, fonts etc. have been fully loaded, replace `DOMContentLoaded` with the `load` event:

```
document.addEventListener('load', function() { /* your code */ });
```